# Produce a recursive list of timestamps and full paths of files in Bash

Tags: bash, recursion, path, ls

Recently I read about the following statement which produces a recursive list of full paths:

```
ls -R1 /path | while read l; do
  case $l in
   *:) d=${l%:};;
   "") d=;;
   *) echo "$d/$l";;
  esac;
done
```

by user Idelic on Nov 23 '09 at 23:52. I'm a brave shell-user not that familiar to encode what happens here. Could anyone please tell me, how to modify the code above in order to get the same list plus the timestamp (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm) of ls -l before each element?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `find` in order to achieve what you need.  Saying:

```
 find /path -mindepth 1 -printf "%CY-%Cm-%Cd %CH:%CM %p\n"
```

should help you achieve the desired output.